# The type arguments for method 'SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(HtmlHelper, Expression>, IEnumerable, string, object)' cannot be inferred

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Getting this error, not sure what's causing it:

```
@model DelegatePortal.ViewModels.ImpersonateVendorViewModel
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, new SelectList(Model.Vendors, "Id", "Name"), "Choose a vendor", new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm " })
```

> The type arguments for method
>   'SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(HtmlHelper, Expression>,
>   IEnumerable, string, object)' cannot be inferred from the usage.

Comment: Can you show your model and the controller that returned this View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you added all the properties in the View Model.

Mine was missing Id property:

```
 public class ImpersonateVendorViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }
    }
```